# TSQL, counting pairs of values in a table

Tags: sql, t-sql

Given a table in the format of

```
ID   Forename    Surname
1    John        Doe
2    Jane        Doe
3    Bob         Smith
4    John        Doe
```

How would you go about getting the output

```
Forename  Surname  Count
John      Doe      2
Jane      Doe      1
Bob       Smith    1
```

For a single column I would just use count, but am unsure how to apply that for multiple ones.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT Forename, Surname, COUNT(*) FROM YourTable GROUP BY Forename, Surname
```

Comment: Ah excellent, knew there was a simple way I was missing. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
SELECT Forename, Surname, COUNT(1) AS Num 
FROM T
GROUP BY Forename, Surname
```